# Rendering a VBO to a fullscreen Quad

Tags: java, opengl, render, lwjgl, vbo

I have been trying to render a VBO that is 1/3 of the size of the screen resolution of the screen to a Quad that is the size of the screen. What am I doing wrong?

```
public void initGL() {
    frameBufferID = glGenFramebuffersEXT();
    colorBufferID = glGenTextures();
    depthBufferID = glGenRenderbuffersEXT();

    glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, frameBufferID);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, colorBufferID);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, WIDTH / SCALE, HEIGHT / SCALE, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_INT, (java.nio.ByteBuffer)null);

    glFramebufferTexture2DEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, colorBufferID, 0);

    glBindRenderbufferEXT(GL_RENDERBUFFER_EXT, depthBufferID);
    glRenderbufferStorageEXT(GL_RENDERBUFFER_EXT, GL14.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, WIDTH / SCALE, HEIGHT / SCALE);
    glFramebufferRenderbufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT_EXT, GL_RENDERBUFFER_EXT, depthBufferID);

    glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);
}

public void render() {
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    GLU.gluPerspective(90.0f, WIDTH/(float)HEIGHT, 0.001f, 1000.0f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH / SCALE, HEIGHT / SCALE);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, frameBufferID);

    glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
    // Render game code here
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    {
        glVertex2f(0, 0);
        glVertex2f(1, 1);
    }
    glEnd();

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, WIDTH, 0, HEIGHT, 0.001f, 1000.0f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, 0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, colorBufferID);

    glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    glTranslatef(0, 0, -1);
    //Draw Quad
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    {
        glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
        glVertex2f(0, 0);

        glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
        glVertex2f(WIDTH, 0);

        glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
        glVertex2f(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
        glVertex2f(0, HEIGHT);
    }
    glEnd();

    glPopMatrix();
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glPopMatrix();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}
```

I'm trying to render the things in the VBO in Perspective, and then draw the fullscreen Quad in Orthographic. But everything I've tried doesn't work... Like at all. Is there anything I've screwed up?

Answer (score 0):

You are rendering a quad with a completely red texture in front of a red background, so there is not much to see.
The lines you are trying to render into the texture are actually outside of the frustum, as you draw in the z=0 plane, while your frustum is in the range z=[-0.001,-1000].

For debugging purposes, I recommend to change the clear color between your two draw passes, so that you can better see which of the two passes fails.